# How does Admob pay for banner ads?

Tags: advertisements, admob

I want to know how Admob pays for banners? Is it based on time or impressions or count of times that been showed to users?

Comment: I think a better place to find this information would be admob's official documentation. It's going to depend on a lot of factors, like ad format, and what the demand-side is willing to pay for your placement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admob, like most ad services, computes your earnings based on *impressions* (a user saw an ad) and/or *clicks* (a user clicked on the ad).

Admob uses an auction model, so the actual monetary value (to you) of a given impression or click isn't fixed and will depend on what the people buying the ads have bid for the space. Admob will [attempt to display the type of ad that results in the most revenue for you](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3436338?hl=en).

You can view historical trends regarding your earnings in your control panel, along with a variety of reports and metrics that may help you estimate the future revenue for your ad campaigns.